# Chrooting Shell Environment on debian wheezy

Tags: ssh, debian, chroot

I created a chrooted user on a directory `/home/jail`, Inside my /home/jail are the `bin,dev,etc,home,lib,lib64 and usr` directories. /home/jail/ {bin,dev,etc,home,lib,lib64,usr} are all owned by `root:root` I set my user's home directory to `/home/jail/home/user` as shown on my `/etc/passwd` and on my `sshd_config` i have these entries:

```
Match Group jail
 ChrootDirectory /home/jail
```

Of course user is under the jail group

The chrooted user can login but the `bin,dev,etc,home,lib,lib64,usr` directories can be seen by the user, is this normal for chrooted environment?

If i change the `ChrootDirectory` to `/home/jail/home` the shell closes right after putting my password without any trace of error on `/var/log/auth.log`

By the way, i use putty and the server is running debian wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

A `chroot`ed process can see everything inside the chroot. That is perfectly normal, and it couldn't work any other way, if you want to be able to run a normal shell within the chroot.

The point is, you shouldn't put all the normal contents of `/bin`, `/dev`, `/etc` etc. inside the chroot. Instead you should restrict it to only those absolutely needed by the things you intend to run inside the chroot. In particular suid executables are important to keep out of the chroot, because they are the most likely to have exploitable weaknesses.

Comment: Hey thanks, now that clarifies my problem. But i have /home/user on /home/jail also, i was expecting that the user's home directory would be on /home/jail/home/user, how would i do that? Thanks again.

Comment: @user2547024 Once inside a chroot, everything is specified relative to the chroot. So inside the chroot you need to have files in `/etc` specifying users and groups, and inside those any home directory is specified relative to the chroot.